# Why does Google Chrome delay when loading a mp3 radio stream?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio-streaming, howler.js, internet-radio

so here is a mp3 radio stream:

http://studioone-stream.iowapublicradio.org/StudioOne.mp3

when I play it in Firefox or VLC player, it plays instantly, but if I play it in Google Chrome, it will have around 4 seconds delay to load before it plays. What does Chrome do in that 4 seconds?

The reason I am asking is on our website, we are using **`Howler.js`** as the player to play our radio streams, we are running into the same issue, especially if we play the radio stream through Howler player on Chrome, it will add extra 5-6 seconds delay on top of the existing 4 seconds delay, so it will take around 10 seconds in total to load before it plays, weirdly, it plays the same stream through Howler on Firefox still instantly.....I realize the delay happens on any of Chromium based browsers, like Edge.

I was thinking because the stream is HTTP, so Chrome takes few seconds to switch it to HTTPS, but it does not explain why Firefox plays it instantly, Firefox also switches HTTP to HPPTS automatically?

Wondering if the issue is related to browser or related to Howler player?

Comment: "convert it to HTTPS", no that's not a thing. At most browsers *switch* to HTTPS stream if available